# IEEE802.3af, 802.3at @ 2 x 30 Watt. But now @ 2 x 75 Watts

Tags: poe

I have built large networks with IEEE802.3af & IEEE802.3at in PoE midspan and endspan style.

I favor 48VDC, because it is the only standard used world-wide. AC can be anything depending the continent... Each serious telecom equipment manufacturer has them in their portfolio.

We can power phones, fixed and PTZ camera's and IoT devices over cat 5/6 UTP cabling, but when you say that you want to power a serious server, everybody starts shaking there head. No can do..

Research shows that UTP cabling when using 4 pairs can support 160 Watts up to 20 meters. In the case of GB ethernet, you need two 1on1 separation transformers for each pair (so 4 times) to be able to inject and extract the superimposed 48 VDC.

But nobody builds transformers for > 30 Watts... Simply because there is no standard supporting 2 x 75 Watts...

Forget separate power cables. Want to save copper. Superimposing an Ethernet signal on a DC source is as old as Alexander G. Bell, so I guess it should be possible.

Anyone on designing new IEEE802.3a(z)?

Fred

Comment: Do you have a specific question (soliciting opinions results in closed questions)?

Comment: @FredArendse This site is not for discussion ( if you need to there is a chat feature). Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get how you go from 160W over 4 pairs to 2 times 75W. That said:

One of the issues with PoE is heat. I've heard various accounts of people having issues with cables going bad over time because they get warm and it ages the conductor. Sure, even if you go pushing 160W through a single cat5e cable, you are only going to be dealing with about 300mW per meter (based on the assumption that you have 24AWG copper, 48V at load, 40W per pair). But the thing is that these cables are often bundled up. The inner cores can't get rid of the heat, and even though it's only a very small amount of power, their actual temperature does run up high (think about it, if you have a bundle of 48 cables coming from a switch that 300mW is suddenly going towards 15W per meter, with the center cables having no way to dissipate the heat. And on top of that, if you are running an average of 50m to every load, you are wasting 750W of power!

There is also the fact that PoE is designed for low-power loards: IP cameras, wireless AP's, phones, etc. If you are dealing with servers, you likely have acces to power already. Why would you want to run it over ethernet cables, that waste more power in the process, increase the cost of the circuits, ... 
On top of that, with fiber becoming more and more commonplace...

Comment: Hi Joren, here is why..

first: length of UTP will be max 5 meters
second: no cable bundling

think of a 24 port midspan power injector, max 5 m UTP and a splitter. The last is required simply because there aren't any Powered Devices which have 1on1 transformers capable of more than 2 x 30 Watts (at)

I am building a cloud server centre running solely on 48VDC. No general datacenter where you find AC sockets in each rack.

I had that before, but got crazy about AC harmonics, huge cooling stuff and cold corridors and servers running full speed with zero gig traffic in a month.